# Is there a way to return part of an array in a document in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Pretend I have this document:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "friends": [
        "Alice",
        "Joe",
        "Phil"
    ],
    "posts": [
        12,
        15,
        55,
        61,
        525,
        515
    ]
}
```

All is good with only a handful of posts. However, let's say `posts` grows substantially (and gets to the point of 10K+ posts). A friend mentioned that I might be able to keep the array in order (i.e. the first entry is the ID of the newest post so I don't have to sort) and append new posts to the beginning. This way, I could get the first, say, 10 elements of the array to get the 10 newest items.

Is there a way to only retrieve posts `n` at a time? I don't need 10K posts being returned, when most of them won't even be looked at, but I still need to keep around for records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator of mongoDB in projection to get n elements from array like following:

```
db.collection.find({
   //add condition here
  }, {
    "posts": {
    $slice: 3 //set number of element here
      //negative number slices from end of array
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this :
create a list for posts you want to have (say you want first 3 posts) and return that list

```
for doc in db.collections.find({your query}):
    temp = ()
    for i in range (2):
        temp.push(doc['posts'][i])
    return temp
```

Comment: This will still do the big query to the DB